# What should be the expected value in the unit test

Tags: unit-testing

Hi I am new on unit test and I am writing this localization unit test method but I am not sure what would be the expected value for it.

**Here is the function that to be tested:**

```
 public static string GetStringResource(string language, string name)
    {
        Localization cfg = GetInstance();
        try
        {
            if (cfg != null && cfg._config != null)
                return cfg._config.GetValue(language, name).ToString();
            return string.Empty;
        }
        catch { return string.Format("Localization Error: '{0}:{1}' Not Found.", language, name); }
    }
```

**Here is the GetValue function:**

```
public override object GetValue(string section, string entry)
    {
        VerifyAndAdjustSection(ref section);
        VerifyAndAdjustEntry(ref entry);

        try
        {
            //XmlDocument doc = GetXmlDocument();
            XmlElement root = doc.DocumentElement;

            XmlNode entryNode = root.SelectSingleNode(GetSectionsPath(section) + "/" + GetEntryPath(entry));
            return entryNode.InnerText;
        }
        catch { return null; }
    }
```

**Here is my unfinished test method:**

```
public void GetStringResourceTest()
    {
        string language = "English"; // TODO: Initialize to an appropriate value
        string name = "John Smith"; // TODO: Initialize to an appropriate value
        string expected = language; // TODO:" Initialize to an appropriate value
        string actual;
        actual = Localization.GetStringResource(language, name);
        Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);

    }
```

Comment: First, what's the language?  Second, if you don't know the behavior of this block of code, why would you expect total strangers to?  Writing unit tests is all about testing behavior given certain input.

Answer (score 1):

When you're unit testing, you're trying to validate that, for a given set of inputs, you have the correct outputs.

In this case, you have two inputs: `language` and `name`.

Presumably, given a certain combination of the two, there's an expected output. You, as the developer, should have the toolset necessary to determine that and validate whether it's correct. Then, once you have a test written, you'll never have to manually validate that behavior again!

For example, if you were unit testing a calculator, you might test the `Add` method by asserting that given `1+1`, the output is `2`.

Comment: I didn't write the original code so the expected output is a little confusing here. At least what the path I should go to find out?

Comment: Talk to whoever wrote the original code if possible. Failing that, talk to another team member who knows more about it. Failing *that*, talk to one of the business users and/or product owners.